# How can I deactivate some Markdown parsing rules in Mistune?

Tags: python-3.x, markdown

How can I deactivate some Markdown parsing rules in [Mistune](http://mistune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

For instance I would like enable only `**bold**` and `*italic*` and deactivate all other rule parsing.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom `renderer`.
A `renderer` is a `class` and each `rule` is a `method` of that `renderer` `class`.
To have your own rules, you need to either override a method and make it do nothing (Method A below), or to replace the full list of `default_rules` (method B below)

**Method A)**

Override a rule method: [Here](http://mistune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#developer-guide) is the full list of rules.

E.G.:

```
class YourRenderer(mistune.Renderer):
    #example of rule
    def block_code(self, code, lang):
        pass 

renderer = YourRenderer()
markdown = mistune.Markdown(renderer=renderer) # this renderer won't have the block_code rule
```

**Method B)**

Tamper with `default_rules` array

A `renderer` has an own property called `default_rules`. You just need to create a custom renderer and modify that array to your liking. Here's a sample `class` to get you started

```
class CustomRenderer(InlineLexer):
        # Modify this array as you like
        # you can insert or delete whatever rules it has
        self.default_rules.insert(3, 'some_function')
```

*I didn't test this*